# How to execute a function for a particular time period in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working in angularjs and ionic project. Here I need to change the state and after 10 seconds, I need to come back to the previous state.
Below is my code:

```
if (response.data[i].id == opport.id && response.data[i].status == 2 && response.data[i].contractor_fse_counterprice == "accept") {
    $state.go("tab.chats");
    /*setTimeout(function () {
        $state.go("tab.chats")
    }, 10000);*/
}
```

How can I implement the time interval for execution of the function of changing state and returning back after 10 seconds in angularjs?

Answer (score 1):

AngularJs has a `$timeout` function.

Simply inject $timeout in your controller and then use it in the format below;

```
$timeout(function()  {
  // what to call
$state.go("tab.chats")
}, 10000) // 10000 = 10 seconds
```